# UITableView scroll to the top of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have an UITableViewController with 3 static cells. One with the height of 60.0 at the top and one with the same size at the bottom. The height of the mid cell is dynamic and so big, that all 3 cells together fill the whole screen.
The mid cell contains an UITextView which fills the complete cell.
My problem is that when I want to type something in that TextView the tableview automatically scrolls when the keyboard is rising and I don't see the top of the cell including the cursor anymore until I manually scroll back there.
Is there any way I can prevent the table view from scrolling like this automatically? Or tell it that it should scroll to the top of the cell so I see the cursor?

I've already tried to override the `viewWillAppear(_:)` method without calling the super method of it but then I can't scroll the tableview manually enough so I can't get to the last cell when the keyboard is visible.
I've also tried to scroll manually to the cell inside the `textViewDidBeginEditing(_:)` but it changed nothing. My method looked like this.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
}
```

I've no idea what else I could try so I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can set the contentInset of the tableView like this:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 80, right: 0)
```

So you can use the bottom to compensate the offsets that you want.

Comment: This makes the tableview scroll even more to the bottom :/ and it doesn't really look good with the huge empty space at the bottom

Comment: Try different values or negative values on the begin editing to adjust it, when the end editing get called, just return it to 0

Comment: I tried different values for bottom and for top but neither of them worked. In fact it only makes it impossible to go to the first/last cell with the keyboard visible. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
mainTableView.scrollsToTop = true
```

OR

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)
```